# Using curl sequences without knowing the ending point

Tags: curl

Is there a way in curl to use sequences but not give it a maximum value? So that it will download everything from the start of the sequence up?

For example:

> curl ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.3/7.3.[548-*]

or something like that?

Comment: In Unix/Linux, the shell expands globs (like your `[548-*]` before the command even gets to see it. To be on the safe side, wrap the URL in single quotes. At least my curl manual gives no such option, you could try `[548-]` (no end) or `[548-1000]`, if it goes only to 563 it should complain it couldn't get 564 to 1000 (but get you the ones you are interested in).

Answer (score 1):

Use curve expansion?

`curl ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.3/7.3.{548..1000}`

Answer (score 1):

Curl doesn't have an option to tell it to stop on the first error. (`-f` doesn't do that: curl still proceeds with the next URL on the command line.)

So let the shell handle the logic. Call `curl` once per URL. Stop at the first error.

```
n=548
while
  curl ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.3/7.3.$n
do
  n=$((n+1))
done
```